# Create new concrete object from variable

Tags: swift, oop, generics

I want to create an extension method for any type which returns a new object with the concrete type of the variable, e.g.:

```
class A
{
    required public init() {}
}

class B : A {}

let myProp = B()
doSomethingWith(myProp)

func doSomethingWith(_ prop:A)
{
    // Should create a new object of type B:
    let foo = prop.createNew()
}
```

So far my extension looks like this:

```
extension NSObject
{
    public func createNew() -> T
    {
        let t = type(of: self)
        let new = t.init()
    }
}
```

However it needs to return a generic type and I'm stuck with that. How would I have to implement `createNew()` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `Self`, right?

```
extension NSObject {
    public func createNew() -> Self {
        return type(of: self).init()
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be damned but it works! Looks like I over-complicate the concept.